# JPA - Finding nested entities using combined criterias

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I have an entity named `FileEntity` which contains a list of reports of the type `ReportEntity`.

`FileEntity` has an field which determines, which user has created the file containing a number of reports.

```
@Entity
public class FileEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "user")
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @NotNull
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
           fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
           orphanRemoval = true)
    @NotNull
    private List<Report> reports = new ArrayList<>(5);

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Report {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

I am currently trying to fetch a single report with a given report ID and the ID of the person who issued the file containing the report. The combination is unique, so it should only return one report for a certain combination of report and user ID. But I am unable to retrieve a single result using the following criteria:

```
public Report findReportByUserAndReportId(Long reportId, Long userId) {
    Objects.nonNull(reportId);
    Objects.nonNull(userId);
    try {
        final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<Report> cq = cb.createQuery(Report.class);
        final Root<FileEntity> fileEntity = cq.from(FileEntity.class);
        final Root<Report> report = cq.from(Report.class);
        final Join<FileEntity, Report> join = fileEntity.join(FileEntity_.reports);
        final Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[]{
            cb.equal(join.get("id"),
                     userId),
            cb.equal(join.get(Report_.id),
                     reportId)};
        cq.select(report).where(predicates);
        return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException |
             NonUniqueResultException ne) {
        LOG.log(Level.WARNING,
                "Could not find report: {0}",
                ne.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Has someone an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use multiple roots here, because they generate a carthesian product of all the elements, without joining them. Use joins or `Path`s instead. Second, in the first predicate. `join` object denotes a `Path` of reports, not a user, therefore it doesnt' make sense to look for the `userid` there.

```
Root<FileEntity> fileEntity = cq.from(FileEntity.class);
Path<User> user = fileEntity.get(FileEntity_.user);
Join<FileEntity, Report> reports = fileEntity.join(FileEntity_.reports);
Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[]{
        cb.equal(user.get(User_.id),
                 userId),
        cb.equal(reports.get(Report_.id),
                 reportId)};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are you sure about the class being `Join` in your third line? Furthermore you are using the object `join` in the predicates array. Should this be `reports`?

Comment: Join class in the third line should work fine, but I have fixed the type params. And yes, in the predicates you have to use reports. Let me fix it